# Back to Factory settings except one folder

Tags: macos, mac

I would like to give my mac to another person after a few years.
The mac is full with private and cached data that I obviously can’t find/remember, and a lot of wasted memory usage.

I would like to *delete everything* and back to a "new mac", but **to leave only 1 folder with some data that I want to keep on desktop**.

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

First back up to a USB what you want to keep.

[Then follow instructions from Apple how to ready your Mac.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065)

Do not forget to Log out from iCloud, iTunes, App Store...ect..

Comment: Thanks , can it be done while keeping all the apps on the Mac but removing all kinds of data?

Comment: It can't be done in any way that keeps any apps. The last step is to completely wipe the machine, ready for its new owner. The apps on the machine belong to the original purchaser & cannot be transferred. That includes the OS itself.